# Google Analytics Instant Tester

Tags: javascript, testing, google-analytics

Given that it takes [around 24 hours](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/frequently-google-analytics-update-33562.html) for Google Analytics data to update, this makes it hard to see how data rolls up and is displayed within Google Analytics.

Is there some sort of instant tester, or fast turn around application that allows me to quickly set up custom dimensions/metric within my app and see how they appear?

Comment: Does the real-time thing not work for what you need to check?

Comment: @Huangism I wasn't aware of a real-time thing? Please enlighten

Comment: When you click through to your dashboard, there is a tab on the left that says real-time. I only use that for event tracking check, but you can look around and see if this helps

Comment: @Huangism I am testing GA on my `localhost` using `ga('create', 'UA-63613571-2', {'cookieDomain' : 'none'}); ` , does this work with localhost?

Comment: I am not sure if this works with localhost, I guess if you are not filtering out 127.0.0.1 then it should work? Do you have a dev server or staging server that you can test on? You would ideally want different profiles on GA for the different environments

Comment: @Huangism okay thanks. Real time doesn't seem to offer support for custom metrics/dimensions/events. Only when I go to Dashboards and generate a custom report can I set those. Is there a way to, say, send a custom page view event, `ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1' : 'myVal'}` and see it populate in real time?

Comment: It works for event tracking, if you click on the real-time tab, there is a sub-menu and one of them is events. I think page views just appear on the real-time home screen. I am unsure about the others because I have never used them

Comment: you can fork the data google sends to the mothership to your own server, and run your own stats.

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean the mothership? How is this "forking" done?

Comment: im talking about intercepting the part where GA sends data to the google server, to count the hit. its an image named utm.gif. it's loaded by ga.js as a new dynamic image `new Image(1,1)`. so, if you clobber `Image` to return something that uses a custom setter for .src, your code can get the url of every dynamic image, including the GA tracking pixel, whose GET-param URL has all the analytics data setup by GA. or just copy and edit ga.js and load locally...

Comment: @Growler, I guess dandavis means this ("Tasks" in GA): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#adding.  If you look at the "adding to tasks" there is an example how to send a copy of the data to your own webserver,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options for real time analytics:

- [Google Realtime Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en) - Built into Google Analytics. To use Google Analytics Realtime, login to your google analytics account and select your web property. Then, on the left hand side click Real-Time->Overview.
- [GoAccess](http://goaccess.io/) - If you have access to your web server log files this will give you a real-time view of traffic and does not require anything more than a console access. The really nice things about GoAccess is that it does not rely on any 3rd part services and has the ability to run in real-time or generate reports. To use GoAccess, first install it on your server using either the package manager or in a local directory using the [official Git](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess.git). Then, if you are running a standard Apache configuration just run the executable with:

  `# goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/your-website-access.log -a`

  If you are running a non-standard Apache log configuration (or another web server entirely), then you have to give GoAccess a description of your log file. This can be done in the `~/.goaccessrc` file. Refer to the [GoAccess documentation](http://goaccess.io/man) for specific descriptors in generating a string that describes your log file lines.
- There are also a host of other SAS options like [Clicky](http://clicky.com/), [GoSquared](https://www.gosquared.com/), or [piwik](http://piwik.org/) (which is open source).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible both. However, @rfornal, this does at least meet the minimum standard in the linked post by including a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem.